# MXNet install in R : nocudnn folder

Tags: r, installation, gpu, mxnet

In installation guide...

3.Download the MXNet package as a .zip file from the MXNet Github repository and unpack it. You will be editing the "/mxnet/R-package" folder.

-> OK, I downloaded 'mxnet-master.zip', and found 'R-Package' folder.

4.Download the most recent GPU-enabled MXNet package from the Releases tab. Unzip this file and navigate to the /nocudnn folder. Note: You will copy some of these extracted files into MXNet’s R-package folder. We are now working two folders, R-package/ and nocudnn/.

-> in my case, 
I downloaded 'mxnet-0.9.3.zip', 
The 'nocudnn' folder could not be found.

What mistake did I make ?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the updated instructions from https://gist.github.com/thirdwing/89aa9bfc588ade138496e6932072152c

It has been tested on an AWS EC2 instance with GPU.

[image]